# What is optimized way of forloop

Tags: c#, linq, loops

Which For Loop is **better for performance** likewise coding criteria

```
var totalCount = new List<int>();
```

> 1. Foreach

```
 foreach(var student in StudentList)
 {
      var studentItem= student.DataContext as studentEntity;
      if (studentItem!= null)
      {
            totalCount.Add(studentItem.Id);
      }
 }
```

> 2. ForEach

```
StudentList?.ForEach(student=>
{
    var studentItem= student.DataContext as studentEntity;
    if (studentItem!= null)
    {
        totalCount.Add(studentItem.Id);
    }
});
```

my question is that in **fast performance which loop is more correct**.

If in my `StudentList` there are records around `1000` and above and I want 
to perform logic manipulation in c# then which ForLoop is better for 
**Fast Perfomance**

thank you in advance !!!

Comment: `var totalCount = new List<int>(studentList);`

Comment: @Henrik I believe the ".Add" is just an example ;)

Comment: In your particular case - best performance will be `totalCount = studentList`

Comment: As Dmitry has said, `AddRange` is the best approach in terms of readability and performance. But if that wasn't possible(f.e. because you have to do other things with each item) i'd prefer the plain `foreach`-loop because it also works if the collection is not a list(please never do `sequence.ToList().ForEach(...)`).

Comment: Race your horses, let us know

Comment: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2006/01/20/foreachperf/

Comment: do not stick with example ,my question is all about to performance of loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let .Net do it for you, get rid of any loop:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 totalCount.AddRange(studentList);
```

It's more *readable* and (potentially) more efficient.

**Edit:** If `totalCount` and `studentList` have *different types*, add `Select`, e.g:

```
totalCount.AddRange(studentList.Select(student => student.Id));
```

Comment: Add range is used when we have both list have same kind of type

Comment: do not stick with example my question is all about that loop's performance , which is better fast

Comment: @shivani: If types are *different*, add `Select`

Comment: you mean with compare to both loop , AddRange expression is fast ?

Comment: @shivani: `AddRange` is a *specially designed*, *optimized* by .Net method, that's why it's preferrable than any manual emulation.

Answer (score 0):

They are pretty much the same in terms of optimization, you can check [Eric Lippert's blog: “foreach” vs “ForEach”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/), where he talks about this and shows forEach internally.

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> action)
{ 
  // argument null checking omitted
  foreach(T item in sequence) action(item);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the relevance of the linked article here, since it's rather about the philosophical implications of adding this function to `IEnumerable` instead of the performance effects as asked for, but thanks for the gread link anyways. The article also states that the `ForEach` version might have slight implications due to using a closure.

Answer (score 0):

Another .NET (LINQ) approach for creating list from another list (one-liner for one liner fans)

```cs
var totalCount = studentList.ToList();
```

Another LINQ approach , when you have already existed items.

```cs
var totalCount = new List<int> { 1, 2 ,3 };

var all = totalCount.Concat(studentList).ToList();
```

Impossible to not stick to example, because performance could be achieved only when you know context of the problem.

In your updated example readable and fast enough approach could be

```cs
 var totalCount = 
     StudentList.Select(student => student.DataContext as Entity)
                .Where(entity => entity != null)
                .Select(entity => entity.Id)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: It's OK unless `totalCount` has some elements

Comment: do not stick with example ,that is just example ,my question about performance of loop